# read different fields and pass on to awk to extract those fields

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Probably this is answered somewhere, but the things I have explored is not matching my need.

I would like to read different fields from one file (FILE1) and pass this on to a awk script, which can extract those fields from another file (FILE2).

FILE1

```
1   156202173   156702173
2   26915624    27415624
4   111714419   112214419
```

so read lines from this file and pass it on to the following script

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"};
{if ($1==$1 && $2>= $2 && $2<= $3 ) {print $0}}' FILE2 > extracted.file
```

The FILE2 looks like this;

```
1   156202182   rs7929618
16  8600861 rs7190157
4   111714800   rs12364336
12  3840048 rs4766166
7   20776538    rs35621824
```

so the awk script print only when there is a match with the first field and the value falls between the 2nd and 3rd field. 
Expected output is

```
1   156202182   rs7929618
4   111714800   rs12364336
```

Thanks so much in advance for your response.

Comment: Seems like storing your data in a database and querying via SQL would be a good solution, especially if you have a large volume of data.

Answer (score 1):

there should be plenty of similar questions but writing the script is faster than looking up.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{lower[$1]=$2; upper[$1]=$3; next} 
       lower[$1]<$2 && $2<upper[$1]' file1 file2

1   156202182   rs7929618
4   111714800   rs12364336
```

Comment: thanks so much for your input, it works like a charm.. what if the matching first field is in a different column in the source file.. I suppose NR==FNR might not work in that case...

Comment: `NR==FNR` is for processing the first file, nothing to do with fields.  If matching field index is not 1, change it accordingly.